# Crystallographic point group is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

I have this question that I am trying to write a proof for and for some odd reason I cannot wrap my head around how to write the proof up. I tried using the crystallographic restriction and came up with the result that there are $32$ crystallographic point groups, based off the reasoning that certain symmetry operations on lattices can only have the $1,2,3,4$ or $6$-fold symmetry requirements (which has translation periodicity). So now I am stuck on how to prove that a crystallographic point group is finite. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I assume it is a dicrete subgroup of the compact group $SO_n$ (or $O_n$?), hence finite.

Comment: I am not familiar with SO_n?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you require your point group (or the associated lattice) to be discrete. This means (in one definition) that every two images of lattice points under your group actions will never be closer to one another than some lower bound. One consequence of this is that in every (closed) ball there will only be a finite number of points from your lattice.<sup>1</sup>

You can describe each element of the point group by its effects on three lattice points. There can be only finitely many images of these three in your point group, since they all have same distance to the origin, so you can use that distance as the radius of the ball in the above definition. Hence there can only be a finite number of group actions.

<sup>1</sup>: This roughly corresponds to Marjorie Senechal, *Quasicrystals and geometry*, Definition 1.3 “discrete“ implies Proposition 1.1 “locally finite“. Errors are mine.